# Android date picker result can't able to set text to text view in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-activity, datepicker, fragment, android-alertdialog

I am using DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener to set date to text view. But when trying to set text to text view a null object reference occurs.

code for Showing AlertDialog.Builder

```
void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View customLayout = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_sort, null);
        LiveButton submitBookMark =  customLayout.findViewById(R.id.submitbtthd);
        LinearLayout customDateLinearLayout =         customLayout.findViewById(R.id.customDateLinearLayout);
        TextView InterestNameId = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.InterestNameId);
        fromDate = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.fromDate);
        toDate = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.toDate);
        InterestNameId.setText(title);
        alertDialog.setView(customLayout);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.RGroup);
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();
        fromDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gender", "fromDate");
            binding.filtertxt.setText("Custom Date");
            DatePickerFragment newFragments = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragments.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragments.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        });
        toDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gender", "toDate");
            binding.filtertxt.setText("Custom Date");
            DatePickerFragment newFragments = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragments.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragments.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        });
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = customLayout.findViewById(selectedId);
               if(radioButton.getText().equals("Custom Date")){
                   customDateLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }else {
                   customDateLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

Date picker code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        assert getArguments() != null;
        String gender = getArguments().getString("gender");
        if(gender.equals("fromDate")){
            TextView tv = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fromDate);
            tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(" - ").append(month + 1).append(" - ").append(year));
        }else if(gender.equals("toDate")){
            TextView tv = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.toDate);
            tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(" - ").append(month+1).append(" - ").append(year));
        }else{
            TextView tv = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_Dob);
            tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(" - ").append(month+1).append(" - ").append(year));
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        assert getArguments() != null;
        String gender=getArguments().getString("gender");
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,year, month, day);
        DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();
        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")){
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -21);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -81);
            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            dp.setMinDate(c1.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")){
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -81);
            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            dp.setMinDate(c1.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("fromDate")||gender.equalsIgnoreCase("toDate")){
            long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
            c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -81);
            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            dp.setMaxDate(time);
            dp.setMinDate(c1.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
            long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
            c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -100);
            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            dp.setMaxDate(time);
            dp.setMinDate(c1.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        else{
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -21);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -81);
            c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            dp.setMinDate(c1.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        return dpd;
    }

}
```

**error :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                            at com.app.app.Fragments.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:23)
                                            at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:173)
                                            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:188)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

While trying to set the value to textview inside the dialog is the reason for the error. Anybody have a proper solution for this?

**error occuring line ===>**
TextView tv = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fromDate);
tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(" - ").append(month + 1).append(" - ").append(year));

Answer (score 1):

`DialogFragment` has it's own root view, so trying to find the `TextView` is not gonna work instead you should create and pass `interface`

```
interface DateSetDelegate {
  void onDateSet(String text);
}
```

In `ShowAlertDialog`

```
 fromDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gender", "fromDate");
            binding.filtertxt.setText("Custom Date");
            DatePickerFragment newFragments = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragments.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragments.setDateSetDelegate(new DateSetDelegate{
               @Override
               public void onDateSet(String text) {
                  fromDate.setText(text);
               }
            });
            newFragments.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        });
        toDate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gender", "toDate");
            binding.filtertxt.setText("Custom Date");
            DatePickerFragment newFragments = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragments.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragments.setDateSetDelegate(new DateSetDelegate{
               @Override
               public void onDateSet(String text) {
                  toDate.setText(text);
               }
            });
            newFragments.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        });
```

In Dialog fragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    private DateSetDelegate delegate;
    
    void setDateSetDelegate(delegate DateSetDelegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // No need to check condition here again, as this instance is already called using condition
        if(delegate != null) {
           delegate.onDateSet(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append(" - ").append(month+1).append(" - ").append(year));
        }
    }
```